# Merge Two objects into a single PHP object

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have come across a really clever way of doing this. But I only used it once so I can't remember where I found the actual snippet.

I have a class called;

```
Worksheet {
    private $settings
    ...
    funnction GetSettings (){}
    ...
}
```

This class has methods, private properties and may extend from an existing class. At runtime I create an object from the class, "process it" and save it in a session so that it can be used by the visitor in a session. At each request I have to get the object from the session feed it back to my processor so that the object properties can be updated (Usually made of multi-dimensional arrays).

I have a simple method in my Processor class that creates the original prototype and mounts the session object to the prototype.

```
class Processor {
    public function Mount ($worksheetObject){
        $this->NewWorksheetPrototype (); //Recreate worksheet from prototype.
        require ('includes/mount.php'); //This will go through the provided Object and mount it on to the processor.
   }
}
```

Of course I don't want to go through the entire object recreate the properties which may contain lots of multi-dimensional arrays. Is there a reliable way of doing this? I know I can do this

$obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $obj1, (array) $obj2);

...but the methods will not be merged.

It is not possible to save an object in a session with the methods attached? I am working in a Symfony2 environment if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you're on PHP 5.4 or greater, you could try something like this:

```
trait MergeableTrait{
    protected $mergedObject;
    public function merge($object2){
        $this->mergedObject;
    }
    public function __get($name){
        if(property_exists($this->mergedObject, $name)){
            return $this->mergedObject->{'$name'}; //Pretty sure that's how it works.....
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("{$name} is not an available property");
    }
    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        if(method_exists($this->mergedObject, $name)){
            return call_user_func_array([$this->mergedObject, $name], $arguments);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("{$name} is not a callable method");
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should give you a good idea on how to do this. Provided your concrete classes don't have `__call` or `__get` methods defined, you can add the merge behavior like so:

```
class Worksheet{
    use MergeableTrait;
    ...
}
```

...or wherever you need it.

Then you can do something like this:

```
$ws = new Worksheet();
$proc = new Processor();
$ws->merge($proc);
```

**This is not tested, nor would I recommend doing things this way as it makes things much harder to debug**

Also keep in mind that this won't take into account the visibility of your methods and properties. I would recommend perhaps expanding the checks to include some basic reflection, but overall, this should give you a head start.